# I'm having trouble returning a List from a method in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I'm learning about Lists in java but I'm having a hard time returning it from a method like I would any primitive data type.  All I'm trying to do is return a list of nodes and then print out all their labels.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class TestingArrays 
{

    List<Node> myList1  = new ArrayList<Node>();

    List<Node> myList2 = new ArrayList<Node>();

    List<Node> myList3 = new ArrayList<Node>();

    List<Node> myList4 = new ArrayList<Node>();

    private Node Node1 = new Node("One", myList1);
    private Node Node2 = new Node("Two", myList2);
    private Node Node3 = new Node("Three", myList3);
    private Node Node4 = new Node("Four", myList4);

    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        List<Node> nodeList = nodeArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.println(nodeArray.get(i).label);
        }
    }

    public List<Node> nodeArray()
    {
        List<Node> tempList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        tempList.add(Node1);
        tempList.add(Node2);
        tempList.add(Node3);
        tempList.add(Node4);
        return tempList;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem you are having? What doesn't work?

Comment: Code won't compile because nodeArray isn't static. And the println statement references a non-existent variable called nodeArray rather than nodeList. edit: but if nodeArray was static it still wouldn't compile because it references non-static member fields.

Comment: Also, for iteration over list-items, a foreach (or as it's called in java: "extended for"-loop) should be used.

Comment: Thanks Dunes, I missed that mistake regarding the nodeList instead of nodeArray.  Am I required to make my nodeArray() method static?  Is there a way to proceed with this without making it static?

Comment: @AskingQuestions If you want to define a method in Class A and place a `main` in Class A, then any methods in Class A that you wish to use in `main` must also be static.

Comment: Just realized this is 5 years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't call non static method from static context. make method `nodeArray()` `static`. That'll fix your problem.

also you cannot make a static reference to the non-static field i.e. `Node1`, `Node2`, `Node3`, `Node4`. so make them `static` too.

also `nodeArray.get(i).label` is wrong as it should be `nodeList.get(i).label`.

Answer (score 1):

this is weird:

```
nodeArray.get(i)
```

nodeArray is a function . how could it even compile? that's why it's important to give good names to both functions and variables.

also , since it's a list , you can use foreach , like this:
http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/loops/foreach.html

oh , and in the main function you should either create a new instance of the class and use it , or set all of the methods and variables as static.

Answer (score 1):

The nodeArray() method is a method for the TestingArrays object.  All the nodes and lists are attributes of the TestingArrays object.

You need to create a TestingArrays object to access those things.

Replace your main method with this code:

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    List<Node> nodeList = new TestingArrays().nodeArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(nodeList.get(i).label);
    }
}
```